# What is the difference between these statements? $\forall x: P(x) \wedge \forall y:Q(y)$ and $\forall x \forall y:P(x) \wedge Q(y)$

Tags: logic

What is the difference between these statements?

$$\forall x: P(x)  \wedge \forall y:Q(y)$$
$$\forall x  \forall y:P(x) \wedge Q(y)$$

Comment: No difference...

Comment: The first statement has 2 colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same. The first statement asserts that $P(x)$ is true for all $x$ and that $Q(y)$ is true for all $y$.

The second statement asserts that $P(x) \wedge Q(x)$ is true for all $x$ and $y$, but this thus implies that $P(x)$ is true for all $x$ and $y$ **and** $Q(x)$ is true for all $x$ and $y$, which is the same thing.